# 3D scanning parts that don't stand on their own

Tags: 3d-models, scanning

All the scanners I have seen, are scanning objects that stand on a platform. What about something like a plastic part which doesn't stand on it's own? for example this [plastic piece](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/155528855558?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=155528855558&targetid=1817264050035&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=1007230&poi=&campaignid=19097525516&mkgroupid=147591788601&rlsatarget=pla-1817264050035&abcId=9303861&merchantid=431985279&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIluvt16TS_wIVVsDtCh0-dwZhEAQYAyABEgJnR_D_BwE) I broke on my Kärcher pressure washer

[image]

Do you just have to be skilled at modelling enough to create a model from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At work we print holders for parts that don't standup themselves. This part you broke is probably not suitable for being printed yourself, this is most probably Nylon (or even worse, POM), when you print this yourself you will get into some challenges, like warping. If this has been broken, I doubt whether you find a suitable replacement material. Personally, I would buy this part, it is too difficult to scan and print yourself. And, if printed outside using a print service, it will be more expensive then buying a spare.

Comment: ok so you print a holder to hold the part you're scanning but wouldn't the holder be scanned into the model as well? how would you get rid of the holder?

Comment: You need to edit the scan anyways. I've done it a few times, lots of work afterwards repairing or redrawing the object.